# NSInterger Max and Minimum Value

Tags: count, ios7, nsinteger

in my app I'm taking into account the clicks made ​​on a botton . The number of clicks is displayed in a label and I used this code ... I wish that the number of clicks started not from 0 but from 12 and stop automatically at 30.
How can I give these blocks in my action where I draw the NSInterger ?

Thank you all for the help

```
@ interface FFDettagliEsami () {
    NSInteger FFVariabileNumerica_CFU_Votazione ;   
}

@ end

@ implementation FFDettagliEsami
   
- ( IBAction ) FFAddVotazione : (id ) sender {
    FFVariabileNumerica_CFU_Votazione + + ;
    [ FFVotazioneLabel setText : [ NSString stringWithFormat : @ " % d", FFVariabileNumerica_CFU_Votazione ]] ;
}
```

Comment: I highly doubt the `+ +` operator exists with a space between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize `FFVariabileNumerica_CFU_Votazione` to whichever value you want in places like `viewDidLoad:` or `initWith...` if it's a view controller.

And for stopping at 30, just add a check :

```
- (IBAction)FFAddVotazione:(id)sender {
    if (FFVariabileNumerica_CFU_Votazione >= 30)
        return;

    FFVariabileNumerica_CFU_Votazione++ ;
    [FFVotazioneLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", FFVariabileNumerica_CFU_Votazione]];
}
```

Comment: Cyrille Hello and thank you for your answer ... I initialized in viewDidLoad

     FFVariabileNumerica_CFU_Votazione = 12;

When I start the bill, starting directly from 12 to 30 but does not stop how can I set the lock?
This is when I need to add value and when it subtracts ... How can 'solve? Thank you so much Rory

Comment: Perfect Answer! this is Correct! Thanks Cyrille and Thanks ManicMonkOnMac!! Thanks for your Answer

Answer (score 1):

use

static NSInteger FFVariabileNumerica_CFU_Votazione = 12;

and in - ( IBAction ) FFAddVotazione : (id ) sender

add the condition to check for FFVariabileNumerica_CFU_Votazione < 30

if(FFVariabileNumerica_CFU_Votazione < 30){
    FFVariabileNumerica_CFU_Votazione++;

}